# make ID field required with MongoEngineObjectType

Tags: mongodb, graphql, mongoengine, graphene-python

I use graphene with graphene-mongo. My graphql schema has a type similar to this:

```
type Report {
   id:ID!
   name:String!
}
```

My graphene class for this type is

```
class Product(MongoengineObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = MongoProduct
```

and the mongoengine class is

```
class MongoProduct(mng.DynamicDocument):        
    name = mng.fields.StringField(required=True)
```

How can I make the field `id` required? GraphiQL shows an exclamation mark next to `name`, but not next to `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MongoProduct(mng.DynamicDocument):
    id = ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, required=True)    # Optional: Add default=bson.ObjectId        
    name = mng.fields.StringField(required=True)
```

`id` can also be a IntField or a StringField but I'd recommend to stick to an ObjectId